# Blender 2.8 doesn't load after installation on Windows 7

Tags: error

Opening blender in debug mode logged the following

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.80 (sub 75)
Build: 2019-07-29 09:44 AM Windows
argv[0] = blender
argv[1] = --debug
argv[2] = --python-expr
argv[3] = import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.sysinfo(filepath=r'C:\Users\PCWORL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs\blender_system_info.txt')
read file
  Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
Win32 Error# (0): The operation completed successfully.
```

**More in depth details here:**
https://www.notion.so/Blender-Setup-issues-61b41b9449a34a96afc39681c2054fbf

If all else fails, can I use the following dll file from blender ftp site:
https://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/win64/

P.S. My machine is an old one but not sure if this error is dependent on it.

Comment: First check if your system meets the minimum requirements. https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: Intel Mobile 4 has OpenGL 2.0, maybe 2.1. Blender 2.8+ needs OpenGL 3.3 or higher. Blender 2.79 was the last Blender version to support OpenGL 2.1, you might want to try that one.

Comment: @metaphor_set. Upon your advice, I could download and start using 2.79 version. Thanks. I was more keen on using 2.8 as it claims to be best blender version for 2D animation which I was hoping to use for Silhouette animation.